# Quickblox: Android Video Calling Shows java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method registerComplexPropertyParser

Tags: java, android, quickblox

Used native-libs.jar. Following the same method as given in the sample. Currently using quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc-2.4. Trying using the sample code  QBRTCClient  shows the below error message:

```
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method     registerComplexPropertyParser(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/quickblox/chat/propertyparsers/MessagePropertyParser;)V in class Lcom/quickblox/chat/model/QBChatMessageExtension; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatMessageExtension' appears in /data/app/xxx.xxx.xxx/base.apk)
                                                                                                 at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.RTCSignallingMessageProcessor.<clinit>(RTCSignallingMessageProcessor.java:38)
                                                                                                 at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCClient.<init>(QBRTCClient.java:93)
                                                                                                 at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCClient.getInstance(QBRTCClient.java:124)
                                                                                                 at xxx.xxx.xxx.Activity.CallActivity.initQBRTCClient(CallActivity.java:125)
                                                                                                 at xxx.xxx.xxx..Activity.CallActivity.onCreate(CallActivity.java:119)
                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2312)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2421)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5329)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using multiple version of library for chat, video and core, so i contacted Quickblox and they told me to use the same version of library for all. Hope this helps.

Thank You